# How could I grab all chat messages in a specific channel in a discord server using discord.py?

Tags: discord, bots, discord.py

My bot has admin permissions, so I was just wondering if it is possible to grab all messages from 1 channel, for example #general.

Answer (score 1):

**Channel history**

This is possible, there is a function that does just that: [`channel.history()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.0/api.html#discord.TextChannel.history)

This function can be used to retrieve all messages sent in a channel. It is however very slow if you want to retrieve all messages in a channel with thousands of messages.

---

**Example**

This example shows how you can retrieve every message sent in a certain channel:

```
async def get_history_of_channel(channel):
    messages = await channel.history(limit=None) # adding None lets us retrieve every message
    for message in messages:
        # do something with that message
        print(message.content)
```

---

**References**

- [Message object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.0/api.html#discord.Message)
- [Channel object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.0/api.html#discord.TextChannel)
- [Channel history](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.0/api.html#discord.TextChannel.history)

Answer (score 0):

- You can do this using [channel.history](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.0/api.html#discord.TextChannel.history)
- `map` to apply a function to each element.
- `flatten` to make it into a single list.

You can change the limit to `None` to get all message but it will take some time.

```py
def transform(message):
    return message.content


@bot.command()
async def history(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    messages_in_channel = await channel.history(limit=10).map(transform).flatten()

    print(messages_in_channel)
```

Usage: `{prefix}history #channel_mention`

Comment: will print put it in console? the bot wont say this right

Comment: This is just to show you want is the data. You can output it the way you want for example. `await ctx.send('\n'.join(messages_in_channel))`. Keep in mind there is a character limit.